# Where can I get shapefiles for changing German territory during the Second World War?

Tags: data-request, historical, europe, geospatial

I am looking to get ArcGIS shapefiles for changes in the territory of Germany throughout World War Two.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the [spatial history project](http://web.stanford.edu/group/spatialhistory/cgi-bin/site/index.php), which give month to month changes of the front lines. [The article](https://web.stanford.edu/group/spatialhistory/cgi-bin/site/pub.php?id=51) covers all interesting information and you can download the dataset (after the first figure) - viz., [EuropeanBorders_WWII.zip](https://web.stanford.edu/group/spatialhistory/Publications/HolocaustGeographies/EuropeanBorders_WWII.zip) (~260 MB).

Comment: This link appears to be dead.